# Google App Engine Using mapreduce perform operation on entity of a datastore with specific key

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using mapreduce to perform operation on a datastore entity, the problem is i want to get only single record corresponding to a specific key , i give the key in the key_range parameters of the inputreader but the reader is still bringing all the data from the datastore. how can i limit the input reader to bring just one record from the datastore.

Comment: What's the point of doing a mapreduce on a single entity?

Comment: the entity has child entities with text in them , i want to count terms frequency in all the child entities

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to run M/R on a single entity in order to then iterate over these child entities, you won't be getting the benefits of the mapper anyway.

Instead, why not use a [task](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) (if you need to start this operation in response to a user action) or a [cron job](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) (if you just need to run the operation periodically)? It will be easier to set up than M/R anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to use for that is the mapper API, it's simply a task to iterate through queried entities:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred

If you are using ndb I have an ndb version at

http://blog.altlimit.com/2013/05/simple-mapper-class-for-ndb-on-app.html